# Get nid inside preprocess function

Tags: theming

My goal is to have an additional region class, when region is rendered on my page--node--9
I am using this `template_preprocess_region()` function to do this.

But how i can get inside my function ID of page, region is rendered on?

Comment: `nid` means Node ID, clarify your question.

Comment: I have page that is customized by page--node--9.tpl.php. That page contain a region, and only on this page it should have additional class. How can i do this via preprocess function i mentioned? I mean how to pass page number, in this case 9 into my preprocess function, to create condition?

Answer (score 1):

From another implementation of the same hook I found out that the node is actually available through the following. Try it out.

```
  $node = $variables['node'];
```

From there you can get node id.